# Note board Web Part Security Permissions

Tags: web-part, permissions, security, collaboration

I have a note board web part sitting on the default.aspx page of a site.  I have both farm and site admin rights over the site and against each comment I can see a delete link - both for my own posts and for others. A user of the site has Contribute rights and cannot see the delete link for other's posts.  Can anyone tell me what permission is required to be able to delete other's comments from the note board?

Many thanks,

Greg

Answer (score 1):

I found this article:  [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sanjaynarang/)
that seems to have some useful information.

Comment: I have tidied this up a little for you, but please expand on how the article helped you, rather than just provide a link. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but I also found that link and can't see how it applies to my problem.